# MVC3 Website throws wingdings error message on localhost

Tags: model-view-controller, visual-studio-2015, runtime-error, wingdings

When I run my MVC3 project on VS2015 it throws an error page with wingding like characters.

1. The website is running on .Net 4 framework
2. Custom errors is set to off
3. Project was pulled from TFS and I've confirmed that all the reference and DLL's are present

Answer (score 0):

I eventually installed MVC2, 3 and 4 and it resolved the error. I must of been missing some VS files or the VS install didn't install properly.

Answer (score 0):

Mvc3 is not supported after VS2010.I use VS2010SP1. You may make it work but it will bite you in the end. You have to choose the VS version and the corresponding Mvc version.